# hasOne relationship and associate()?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this relationship :

```
  public function company(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\User','personal_users_business_users', 'user_id', 'business_user_id');
    }
```

When i try this:

```
  $user->company()->associate($business_user_id);
```

Im getting this error:

> Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::associate()

I have pivot table `personal_users_business_users` and it has `user_id, business_user_id, approved`

And now i want to insert in that pivot table `business_user_id`. What im doing wrong?

Comment: remove the parentheses after company
like so:   $user->company->associate($business_user_id);

Comment: i got this error then undefined column: 7 ERROR: column users.personal_users_business_users does not exist

Comment: you're defnining your relation wrong: you should change this part:

        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\User','personal_users_business_users', 'user_id', 'business_user_id');

Comment: You are using the wrong relationship (should be belongsToMany because you have a pivot table), the relationship itself isn't making sense because the method name is `company` but you are trying to relating a `user` which is probably causing some confusion, and since it's `belongsToMany`, you should be using the method `attach()` to generate a new pivot table record.

Comment: hasOne has 3 parameters and donot have pivot table.

Comment: Hai, Did u fin the solution for this. . I am having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

`associate()` is a method of the **belongsTo** relationship, but it looks like from the above you are trying to call it via the **hasOne** relationship.

**UPDATE**

You can create a function in your App\Models\User class

```
public function company() {
    return $this->belongsTo('MODEL_OF_COMPANY', 'foreign_key', 'owner_key', 'relation');
}
```

then call `$this->company()->associate($company)`

Comment: update() must be of the type array, integer given, called in

Comment: please see answer update. Also I didn't fully understand User belongs to company, or company belongs to user?

Comment: I have two type of users: personal_users and business_user . Business user is like company and he can have many personal_users. Now what i want is to create that relationship I have model PersonalUser, Businessuser, User

Comment: If business user can have many personal users, why you used hasOne() ? You need to use hasMany()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134195/discussion-between-none-and-avik-aghajanyan).

Answer (score -1):

Your relationship should be like this:

```
 public function company()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class);
    }
```

**User** is the model you want to connect with,

and you should call the relationship like this:

```
 $user->company->business_user_id;
```

**$user** must be the Model you have the relationship function in.
**company** is the function and the **business_user_id** the field you want to get

Comment: i dont want to get i want to store data in pivot table